# How to select td on basis of input name using Jsoup in android?

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup for Html Parsing in android.This is the html table i want to parse:

```
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="lccp_trndtl" VALUE="12708NZM KCG YNNYNYNYA"ONCLICK="return farefill('12708NZM KCG YNNYNYNYA','12708','NZM ',0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)" CHECKED>12708</TD>
```

`I need the value of <td> here i.e 12708`.I am using following code to achieve my purpose:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage.trim());

        Elements links = doc.select("table tr td input");

        if(links != null && links.size() != 0)
            Log.v("",String.valueOf(links.size()));
        else
            Log.v("","Size of links is 0");

        for (Element link : links) 
        {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            Log.v("",linkHref);

            String linkText = link.text();
            Log.v("",linkText);
        }
```

I have searched a lot but did not find the solution of my problem.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the input name specify a `<td>` in this markup? It is not obvious; please clarify.

Comment: Sir,i want to select this particular <td> having value 12708.I am not sure whether i can search it by using the input type and name specified inside it.

Comment: So you just want the `<td>` which contains the `<input>`? That has nothing to do with the `<input>`'s `name` attribute.

Comment: yes sir,i exactly want the same.Can you please tell me how to search that particular <td> and extract its value i.e 12708 from whole html web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way it will print your required output

```
     String s="<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=\"RADIO\" NAME=\"lccp_trndtl\" VALUE=\"12708NZM KCG YNNYNYNYA\" ONCLICK=\"return farefill('12708NZM KCG YNNYNYNYA','12708','NZM ',0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)\" CHECKED>12708</TD>";
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s.trim());

     Elements links = doc.getAllElements();

     if(links != null && links.size() != 0)

         Log.v("output",String.valueOf(links.size())+" "+ links.get(0).text());
     else
         Log.v("output","Size of links is 0");
```